# maybe a bug? Unanswered Tags "html" missing

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Sometimes if I just click on Unanswered then the Unanswered Tags "html" is missing in the right column, just sometimes (but mostly). if I scroll down the page I see unanswered html questions...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not a bug. Only the 25 tags with the most unanswered questions are shown. Since there are only nine [unanswered questions tagged with](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/html) [html](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html), it doesn't appear in the list.

---

By the way, **I strongly encourage everyone** to dig though the [unanswered questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/unanswered/) once in a while and answer one. You'll improve your reputation, the internet, and help us [make progress in the beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review).

Comment: thanks for your reply (I havent even got enough points to upvote your answer:..)

Comment: Just a note: Writing answers instead of comments would also increase the answer ratio.